# ticked values are not getting save in database on submit button

Tags: asp.net

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select distinct a.SubMenu_id,b.Submenu_name from SubmenuRec a,Submenu b where a.SubMenu_id=b.SubMenu_id order by 1";
             cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();

            DataSet dssub = new DataSet();

            cmd.CommandText = "select SubMenu_id from SubmenuRec where Menu_id='" + strParam + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dssub);



            for (int j = 0; j <= dssub.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox CheckBox1;
                    CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect");

                    string st = GridView1.DataKeys[i].Values[0].ToString();

                    if (dssub.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == st)
                    {
                        CheckBox1.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }}

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string st = "";
            string strParam = Request.QueryString["submenuid"] + "";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd1.CommandText = "delete from SubmenuRec where SubMenu_id =" + strParam;
                cmd1.Connection = con;
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


                for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox chk;
                    chk = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect");
                    if (chk.Checked == true)
                    {
                        st = GridView1.DataKeys[i].Values[0].ToString();
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SubmenuRec(Menu_ID, SubMenu_id) Values(@MenuID,@SubMenu_id)", con))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MenuID", st);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubMenu_id", strParam);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: no there is no error. i guess there is a problem in insert query